# Change admob ids on existing apps

Tags: java, android, json, admob

I'm studying ad networks for android apps and there's a question that's eating me up.

Admob has two ids. **App id** and **interstitial id**.

After the update "17.0.0" that adds the **AndroidManifest declaration** of the app id **is still possible to change admob account on an existing app** via json?

Example..
My admob account gets banned and I want to **put a new id that's linked on the new account** to keep earning money from the app...
Is possible to do that?

Basically the question is... **Does the app id change on the new account** or is it unique for every app?
Because if it does than I cannot change the id in the manifest and swap accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**is still possible to change admob account on an existing app via json?**

No , i don't think so , because to you have to change your `google-services.json` in your project , and for that you have to download it and copy it into the app/ folder of your Android Studio project

**My admob account gets banned and I want to put a new id that's linked on the new account to keep earning money from the app... Is possible to do that??**

No, sorry. If you got banned there is no point in creating new **Admob** account because you will get banned again. even if you create a new email address ,the moment you leave a small trace to your old account, Google will ban your new account as well.

The small trace can be anything like your phone number, testing devices, developer account, commonly accessed E-mail addresses in the machines and what not you do in internet which could help Google trace back to you. It is very hard to get away with **Google AdMob** ban by simply creating an another account.

Luckily you can still use alternative ad networks like **Unity Ads**, **App Lovin** .....etc but this time try without cheating because consequences can be the same.

Good Luck!

**Does the app id change on the new account  ?**

yes sir ! An app ID is generated based on application and account !

> An app ID is a unique ID number assigned to your apps when they're added to AdMob. The app ID is used to identify your apps. An ad unit ID is a unique ID number assigned to each of your ad units when they're created in AdMob.